# Angular 1.5.x - Issue with nested components

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-components

First of all, I'm using [**`components`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component).

I have this "parent" `component`:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('parentModule', [])
    .component('parent', {
      templateUrl: 'parent.tpl.html',
      controller: ParentCtrl,
        transclude: true,
        bindings: {
            item: '='
        }
    });

  function ParentCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.item = {
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'test'
    };
  }
})();
```

And I'm simply trying to share the `object` *item* with another component, like this:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('childModule', [])
    .component('child', {
      templateUrl: 'child.tpl.html',
      controller: ChildCtrl,
      require: {
        parent: '^item'
      }
    });

  function ChildCtrl() {
    console.log(this.parent)
    var vm = this;

  }
})();
```

**View (Parent):**

```
Parent Component:

<h1 ng-bind='$ctrl.item.name'></h1>
<child></child>
```

**View (Child):**

```
Child component:

Here I want to print the test that is in the parent component
<h2 ng-bind='$ctrl.item.name'></h2>
```

Actually I'm getting the following error:

> Expression 'undefined' in attribute 'item' used with directive
>   'parent' is non-assignable!

Here's the [**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/7AFw41toV3KPPFUpEcWF?p=preview) to illustrate better the situation

Can you explain to me how I can make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `bindings` from yor parent component.
`bindings` binds to the component controller like `scope` binds to a directive's scope. You're not passing anything to `<parent></parent>` So you have to remove it.

Then your child component `require`s a parent component, not an item.
So

```
  require: {
    parent: '^parent'
  }
```

Of course the child template should be modified to:

```
<h2 ng-bind='$ctrl.parent.item.name'></h2>
```

Finally, if from the child controller you want to log the item that is inside the parent, you will have to write:

```
  function ChildCtrl($timeout) {
    var vm = this;
    $timeout(function() {
      console.log(vm.parent.item);
    });
  }
```

I never need the timeout in my components, so there might be something obvious that I missed.

http://plnkr.co/edit/0DRlbedeXN1Z5ZL45Ysf?p=preview

EDIT:

Oh I forgot, you need to use the $onInit hook:

```
this.$onInit = function() {
  console.log(vm.parent.item);
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. So there's no necessity for the use of `transclude: true`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Your child should take the *item* as input via bindings.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('childModule', [])
    .component('child', {
      templateUrl: 'child.tpl.html',
      controller: ChildCtrl,
       bindings: {
        item: '='
       }
    });

  function ChildCtrl() {
    console.log(this.parent)
    var vm = this;

  }
})();
```

So your parent template will look like

```
<h1 ng-bind='$ctrl.item.name'></h1>
<child item="$ctrl.item"></child>
```

The rest should work same.